Output of a Recurrent Neural Network
Reading about RNNs, we always get explained about the unrolled version of it, like this from Colah blog:

In this case, we have 5 timesteps of input data, $X_0$ to $X_4$. And we are predicting at the same timesteps, from $h_0$ to $h_4$.
I don't understand, shouldn't we be predicting at least one step ahead, $h_5$? Or possibly more steps ahead? Let's say $h_5$, $h_6$, $h_7$, $\cdots$?
